How do I dispute the closing of a question that was closed many years ago?
I was in need of an answer to a question, I found someone already asked my question, and it was answered.
What are dot-prefixed variables in R?
The question and answer have received many upvotes, and I have found it useful. I cannot understand why it was closed. I would like to suggest that it be re-opened, as the closed status might suggest to some people that it is not a useful source of information.
Since I have not really participated in the moderation of the site too much, I do not know how to approach this.
Do I need a certain amount of rep to get the ball rolling?

12 and 18 upvotes over 7 years isn't "many"... That said, you need 3000 rep to be able to cast reopen votes. Another option would be to edit the question in such a way that the closure reason gets resolved. That will put the question up for review.

Note that closure doesn't necessarily mean it's not good information. It's just not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

That bullet list at the bottom needs to go first. It is like the question was written to on purpose make people hate it. I not only says "I don't want to do research, you tell me" - this question grabs people by the collar, shakes them violently and screams in their face.

I feel like that may be a good question but it does need an edit. I am personally refraining from doing that since I am not an SME on R.

"I cannot understand why it was closed." This seems pretty obvious: because it lacks focus. There are four sub-questions there: "declaring it", "What it is?", "what is used for?", "some examples". Can you clarify why you don't understand the closure?

Looks to me like a Duplicate anyway of "What does the dot mean in R – personal preference, naming convention or more?" (+96) (and 6 years older), (mentioned in the Comments), which has 2 Answers (+138)&(+31) with much more info than the one Answer (+18) for the Question (+13) you want to get reopened...

@MisterMiyagi, I think "What is it?" and "What is it used for?" are kind of the same question. At least is this case, they have the same answer. From my perspective, I had never seen a variable with prefixed dots, and this question and answer cleared it up for me, so from my perspective, it seemed like a good answerable question.

@Gimby,  I don't think considerations on the style or "personality" of the question should be overly relevant, as long as it is not intentionally being rude.

@ChechyLevas there is a big difference between what should and should not happen, and reality. The reality is that this question was doomed from the beginning.

@chivracq, not really a duplicate but could be considered related.. The question in your link deals with parameter names, and the question I linked to deals with variable names. Part of the answer in your link does actually address the question I linked to, but the questions themselves are not quite the same.

@Cerbrus I think it may be splitting hairs just a bit... a +12/-0 question is not super impressive to folks who've been around a long time and seen questions with scores in the hundreds or thousands, but maybe it should be. A question with 12 upvotes and no downvotes is, objectively, pretty darn well-received, on the whole. That puts it in the top 2.8% of all non-deleted questions, score-wise.

Ah-ah...!, I was right, Qt (Question) now closed as a Duplicate of the Target I mentioned previously...!

All good. I think this episode has now been suitably resolved :)

There are several ways to get a closed question reopened. Here's a non-exhaustive list that covers the typical pathways:

Edit it to fix the closure reason listed in the banner, where possible. On the edit page, there is a checkbox at the bottom that reads something like "This edit resolves the reason for closure, and it should be reviewed for reopening". Make sure that box is checked when you submit your edit, and your edit (though only your first edit as OP, post-closure) will enter the Reopen Votes Review Queue.
In your case, the question was closed as "too broad", now known as "needs focus". This means the question either asks multiple separate things, and/or the question(s) it asks is too broad in scope for the site.
Specifically, your question asked three different questions. Any time you find yourself listing out questions in bulleted or numbered lists, you've gone too far--pick one of them and focus on that. If you have further questions after getting an answer, you can always post a new question.
It looks like a user has already made an edit attempting to focus your question.

Don't edit it, and flag the question (or vote, after you've reached 3,000 reputation) for reopen review.
This typically doesn't go well, because questions tend to be closed for good reason. Sometimes the community disagrees on what's in-scope or a matter of opinion, but generally speaking if your question is closed, chances are you should assume the closure is correct.

Ask about your question on Meta. <-- You are here.
Depending on how well-formed and close to in-scope the question being discussed is, and how earnest the Meta post is in seeking help, there's usually a pretty good chance of getting the question improved, if not reopened altogether. In this case, given the underlying request ("what does .variable mean in R") is in-scope and well-formed, and given the post has a good answer, the edit made by another user (see option 1 above) was enough to get this question of yours reopened.



...until it was re-closed as a duplicate, anyway.

@JohnMontgomery As duplicates go, it's a very good one IMO - especially after the edits. (Of course I have a conflict of interest there ;) ) Asking duplicate questions isn't inherently bad; it can help people later to a) find the canonical and b) recognize that they do in fact have the same problem.
